# How to Bind `$this` to a PHP Function?

Tags: php, oop, closures

As of JavaScript, we can do a thing like this to bind a scope to the desired function:

```
function myFunction() {
    alert(this.foo);
}

var MyClass = function () {
    this.foo = 1;
};

var c = new MyClass();
myFunction.call(c); // `1`
```

I want to do the same thing using PHP. Currently, what I see working successfully is like this, but this only applies to anonymous functions:

```
$my_function = function () {
    var_dump($this->foo);
};

class MyClass {
    public $foo = 1;
};

$c = new MyClass();
Closure::bind($my_function, $c)();

// Or…
// $my_function->call($c);
```

This does not work:

```
function my_function() {
    var_dump($this->foo);
}

class MyClass {
    public $foo = 1;
};

$c = new MyClass();
Closure::bind('my_function', $c)(); // :(
call_user_func([$c, 'my_function']); // :(
```

Comment: This might be slightly off-topic, but it seems logical to ask: Why attempt to do the same thing? PHP isn't Javascript (and I'm glad about that).

Comment: Your question does not make many sense. Probably because you have problem X that you think you can solve with JavaScript solution Y. But then you don't know how to solve Y with PHP. This won't work because Javascript !== PHP. So how about asking for a solution to X not Y?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware @steros So I am trying to make a PHP hook function like in (say) WordPress [1](https://github.com/mecha-cms/genome/blob/6fa7d222768f3c0b9c24c3e3a2a42ccf76eb14ed/engine/kernel/hook.php#L95), [2](https://github.com/mecha-cms/genome/blob/6fa7d222768f3c0b9c24c3e3a2a42ccf76eb14ed/engine/kernel/genome.php#L45), but it is always missing the `this` scope inside the function call unless I have defined it in a function argument. I think this is more to an API style that hopefully can be achieved using the common OOP methods.

Comment: And of course, for things like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52610280/1163000).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using PHP 7.1+, you can convert any PHP callable into a `Closure` using [`Closure::fromCallable`](http://php.net/manual/en/closure.fromcallable.php) (see [PHP: Type hinting - Difference between `Closure` and `Callable`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29730720/php-type-hinting-difference-between-closure-and-callable) for some information about the difference):

```
$closure = Closure::fromCallable('my_function');
```

at which point you can [`bind`](http://php.net/manual/en/closure.bind.php) your object instance to it and execute:

```
Closure::bind($closure, $c)();
```

See https://3v4l.org/aEnSI

Comment: Thanks. It even works with anonymous function without checking whether the input is a closure or a function! ... `Closure::fromCallable($my_function)`

Answer (score 2):

If you follow the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/closure.bind.php#refsect1-closure.bind-examples), this becomes:

```
<?php
$my_function = function() {
  var_dump($this->foo);
};

class MyClass {
  public $foo = 1;
}

$c = new MyClass();
$f = Closure::bind($my_function, $c);
$f();
```